# Sync.ps1 is not digitally signed. You cannot run this script on the current system

Tags: habitat

I'm using Sitecore 9 (Update 2) and have installed Powershell module as well.

Did anyone come across this while running the Unicorn task?

```
[09:10:57] Starting 'Sync-Unicorn'...
Error: C:\Sitecore\habitat\Habitat-1.6\scripts/Unicorn/./Sync.ps1 : File 
Error: C:\Sitecore\habitat\Habitat-1.6\scripts\Unicorn\Sync.ps1 cannot be loaded. The file 
C:\Sitecore\habitat\Habitat-1.6\scripts\Unicorn\Sync.ps1 is not digitally signed. You cannot run this script on the 
current system. For more information about running scripts and setting execution policy, see about_Execution_Policies 
at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ C:\Sitecore\habitat\Habitat-1.6\scripts/Unicorn/./Sync.ps1 -secret 74 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
C:\Sitecore\habitat\Habitat-1.6\scripts\unicorn.js:44
    if (err !== null) throw err;
                      ^
Error: Command failed: powershell -executionpolicy unrestricted "C:\Sitecore\habitat\Habitat-1.6\scripts/Unicorn/./Sync.ps1 -secret 749CABBC85EAD20CE55E2C6066F1BE375D2115696C8A8B24DB6ED1FD60613086 -url https://habitat.sc/unicorn.aspx"
C:\Sitecore\habitat\Habitat-1.6\scripts/Unicorn/./Sync.ps1 : File 
C:\Sitecore\habitat\Habitat-1.6\scripts\Unicorn\Sync.ps1 cannot be loaded. The file 
C:\Sitecore\habitat\Habitat-1.6\scripts\Unicorn\Sync.ps1 is not digitally signed. You cannot run this script on the 
current system. For more information about running scripts and setting execution policy, see about_Execution_Policies 
at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ C:\Sitecore\habitat\Habitat-1.6\scripts/Unicorn/./Sync.ps1 -secret 74 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:291:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:961:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:5)
Process terminated with code 1.
```

I don't see the unblock option either and I tried setting the policy to unrestricted as well: [image]

Comment: Try typing `Get-ExecutionPolicy` in your prompt, and tell us what it returns. Also, are you running this sync process from the command line, or inside Visual Studio?  if Visual Studio, that too needs to be run as administrator.

Comment: I tried running the above script in vs and outside vs(in powershell) as well and both end up with same issue and yes VS is in Admin mode. So `Get-ExecutionPolicy` returns `RemoteSigned`.

Comment: Here is the List :        `MachinePolicy:    RemoteSigned; 
   UserPolicy:    RemoteSigned
      Process :      Undefined
  CurrentUser:    RemoteSigned
 LocalMachine:    Unrestricted`

Comment: I've updated my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you're running a non-admin Powershell console. Try running it as an admin user.

If that is not an option, you may need to unblock the script. Locate it in File Explorer and `Unblock` it.

[image]

Further reference: [Unable To Run Downloaded PowerShell Script](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/rmilne/2015/04/03/unable-to-run-downloaded-powershell-script/)

Edited to add.

If none of this works, you're likely getting an ExecutionPolicy from your AD. You can override this with admin rights. Execute this, in a PowerShell console prompt.

*be aware of the implications of doing this however*

`Set-ExecutionPolicy "Unrestricted" -Scope MachinePolicy -Confirm:$false
Set-ExecutionPolicy "Unrestricted" -Scope UserPolicy -Confirm:$false
Set-ExecutionPolicy "Unrestricted" -Scope Process -Confirm:$false
Set-ExecutionPolicy "Unrestricted" -Scope CurrentUser -Confirm:$false`

Source: [Set-ExecutionPolicy : Windows PowerShell updated your execution policy successfully, but the setting is overridden by a policy defined at a more specific scope!!!](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pasen/2011/12/07/set-executionpolicy-windows-powershell-updated-your-execution-policy-successfully-but-the-setting-is-overridden-by-a-policy-defined-at-a-more-specific-scope/)

Comment: @Vamshi , also make sure that you have set the correct Execution Policy :


Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser Unrestricted

Comment: That is already part of his script though. `powershell -executionpolicy unrestricted`

Comment: oh , I did not know that , thanks !

Comment: @MarkCassidy - Please see my screenshot above. I don't see the unblock option on the file itself. Also I am running the powershell in Admin mode.